# Loading new drivers

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, spi, driver

Suppose I'd like to make changes to the drivers of ADXL345 for SPI by building on https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/no-OS/tree/master/drivers/ADXL345 How should the updated drivers be loaded? Should they be packaged together with the firmware and be compiled together?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is 'standalone' demo code for use on specific (but not mentiond) system, presumably some micro-controller. It uses some other source files that are not in the directory you mention. You can use this code as inspiration for your own code, but it is not a driver that ius ready to be drag-and-drop'ed into your code.